# Yii2 - denyCallback doens't work properly

Tags: yii, yii2

I have this route rule in the **web.php**:

```
'my-stokkee/buy-credits' => 'user/buycredits',
```

And access rule:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),

                'ruleConfig' => [
                    'class' => AccessRules::className(),
                ],
                'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    $this->redirect('login');
                },
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup', 'create', 'reset-password'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'update', 'changepassword', 'buyaccount', 'buycredits', 'to-usd'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['manage'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Instead of redirecting to the **login**, it is redirecting to **my-stokkee/login**. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using full route.

```
return $this->redirect(['/site/login']);
```

Comment: Bah. You beat me by 3 minutes. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the path as configured in your routes e.g:

```
return $this->redirect(['login']);
```

From the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail) (emphasis mine) the `$url` parameter is:

> The URL to be redirected to. This can be in one of the following
>   formats:
>
> - a string representing a URL (e.g. "http://example.com")
> - a string representing a URL alias (e.g. "@example.com")
> - an array in the format of `[$route, ...name-value pairs...]` (e.g. `['site/index', 'ref' => 1]`) `yii\helpers\Url::to()` will be used to
>     convert the array into a URL.
>
> **Any relative URL will be converted into an absolute one by prepending it with the host info of the current request.**